# Error can't get value when using plugin in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I using plugin in jquery about font family:

```
/**
* Font selector plugin
* turns an ordinary input field into a list of web-safe fonts
* Usage: $('select').fontSelector();
*
* Author     : James Carmichael
* Website    : www.siteclick.co.uk
* License    : MIT
*/
jQuery.fn.fontSelector = function() {

  var fonts = new Array(
                'Arial,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif',
                'Arial Black,Arial Black,Gadget,sans-serif',
                'Comic Sans MS,Comic Sans MS,cursive',
                'Courier New,Courier New,Courier,monospace',
                'Georgia,Georgia,serif',
                'Impact,Charcoal,sans-serif',
                'Lucida Console,Monaco,monospace',
                'Lucida Sans Unicode,Lucida Grande,sans-serif',
                'Palatino Linotype,Book Antiqua,Palatino,serif',
                'Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif',
                'Times New Roman,Times,serif',
                'Trebuchet MS,Helvetica,sans-serif',
                'Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif' 
  );

  return this.each(function(){

    // Get input field
    var sel = this;

    // Add a ul to hold fonts
    var ul = $('<ul class="fontselector"></ul>');
    $('body').prepend(ul);
    $(ul).hide();

    jQuery.each(fonts, function(i, item) {

      $(ul).append('<li><a href="#" class="font_' + i + '" style="font-family: ' + item + '">' + item.split(',')[0] + '</a><input type="hidden" id="select_font_family" value="'+item+'" /></li>');
      // Prevent real select from working
      $(sel).focus(function(ev) {

        ev.preventDefault();

        // Show font list
        $(ul).show();

        // Position font list
        $(ul).css({ top:  $(sel).offset().top + $(sel).height() + 4,
                    left: $(sel).offset().left});

        // Blur field
        $(this).blur();
        return false;
      });

      $(ul).find('a').click(function() {
        var font = fonts[$(this).attr('class').split('_')[1]];
        $(sel).val(font);
        $(ul).hide();
        return false;
      });
    });

  });

}
```

And html :

```
<input type="text" value="" id="select_font_family" />
```

with jquery:

```
$('input#select_font_family').fontSelector();
$('ul.fontselector').find('a').click(function() {
    var test = $('input#select_font_family').val();
    alert(test);
});
```

When i click on is result can't get value from , how to fix it ?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Is `ul.fontselector` the right selector? Have you included jquery.js? There could be any number of reasons.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: I have included jquery.js,

Comment: you're constantly double wrapping jQ elements. ie `$(ul)` --> `ul`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that fix you problem, but you're attaching focus and click events N times in $.each it should be attached only once outside each loop.

```
jQuery.fn.fontSelector = function() {

  var fonts = new Array(
                'Arial,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif',
                'Arial Black,Arial Black,Gadget,sans-serif',
                'Comic Sans MS,Comic Sans MS,cursive',
                'Courier New,Courier New,Courier,monospace',
                'Georgia,Georgia,serif',
                'Impact,Charcoal,sans-serif',
                'Lucida Console,Monaco,monospace',
                'Lucida Sans Unicode,Lucida Grande,sans-serif',
                'Palatino Linotype,Book Antiqua,Palatino,serif',
                'Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif',
                'Times New Roman,Times,serif',
                'Trebuchet MS,Helvetica,sans-serif',
                'Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif' 
  );

  return this.each(function(){

    // Get input field
    var sel = this;

    // Add a ul to hold fonts
    var ul = $('<ul class="fontselector"></ul>');
    $('body').prepend(ul);
    $(ul).hide();

    jQuery.each(fonts, function(i, item) {

      $(ul).append('<li><a href="#" class="font_' + i + '" style="font-family: ' + item + '">' + item.split(',')[0] + '</a><input type="hidden" id="select_font_family" value="'+item+'" /></li>');

    });

    // Prevent real select from working
    $(sel).focus(function(ev) {

      ev.preventDefault();

      // Show font list
      $(ul).show();

      // Position font list
      $(ul).css({top:  $(sel).offset().top + $(sel).height() + 4,
                 left: $(sel).offset().left});

      // Blur field
      $(this).blur();
      return false;
    });

    $(ul).find('a').click(function() {
      var font = fonts[$(this).attr('class').split('_')[1]];
      $(sel).val(font);
      $(ul).hide();
      return false;
    });

  });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, a few problems.
The plugin is attaching a new click handler for every font selection.
I rewrote the plugin to fix this.

Second, i recommend triggering an event after the value is updated and bind to that instead of registering yet another click event on the font selector  tag.

Try this:

```
/**
* Font selector plugin
* turns an ordinary input field into a list of web-safe fonts
* Usage: $('select').fontSelector();
*
* Author     : James Carmichael
* Website    : www.siteclick.co.uk
* License    : MIT
*/
jQuery.fn.fontSelector = function() {

  var fonts = new Array(
                'Arial,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif',
                'Arial Black,Arial Black,Gadget,sans-serif',
                'Comic Sans MS,Comic Sans MS,cursive',
                'Courier New,Courier New,Courier,monospace',
                'Georgia,Georgia,serif',
                'Impact,Charcoal,sans-serif',
                'Lucida Console,Monaco,monospace',
                'Lucida Sans Unicode,Lucida Grande,sans-serif',
                'Palatino Linotype,Book Antiqua,Palatino,serif',
                'Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif',
                'Times New Roman,Times,serif',
                'Trebuchet MS,Helvetica,sans-serif',
                'Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif' 
  );

  return this.each(function(){

    // Get input field
    var sel = this;

    // Add a ul to hold fonts
    var ul = $('<ul class="fontselector"></ul>');
    $('body').prepend(ul);
    $(ul).hide();

    jQuery.each(fonts, function(i, item) {

      $(ul).append('<li><a href="#" class="font_' + i + '" style="font-family: ' + item + '">' + item.split(',')[0] + '</a><input type="hidden" id="select_font_family" value="'+item+'" /></li>');
      // Prevent real select from working
      $(sel).focus(function(ev) {

        ev.preventDefault();

        // Show font list
        $(ul).show();

        // Position font list
        $(ul).css({ top:  $(sel).offset().top + $(sel).height() + 4,
                    left: $(sel).offset().left});

        // Blur field
        $(this).blur();
        return false;
      });
    });

    $(ul).find('a').click(function() {
        var font = fonts[$(this).attr('class').split('_')[1]];
        $(sel).val(font).trigger('change');
        $(ul).hide();
        return false;
    });

  });

}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('input#select_font_family').fontSelector();
    $('input#select_font_family').change(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        alert(test);
    }); 
});
```